# Implement Lazy Load for all content inside of ScrollViews

Tags: android

I'm developing a page with a scrollview that has many contents inside of it. the layout of the activity roughly like below :

/--------------------------------
SCROLL VIEW START
/--------------------------------

/---
         HORIZONTAL LISTVIEW 1
/---

/---
         HORIZONTAL LISTVIEW 2
/---

/---
         HORIZONTAL LISTVIEW 3
/---

/---
         HORIZONTAL LISTVIEW 4
/---

/--------------------------------
SCROLL VIEW END
/--------------------------------

as you can see, the activity has a massive content of listview, and inside of listview has an image or text that retrieved from database.

i want to implement a Lazy Load to this activity but don't know what is a good way. All tutorial i look is always for lazy load for a listview but not a scrollview with a massive content.

For now i just using a chronologically load data from database. For example, first i call the code to retrieve data into List View 1, and when its done then call the code to list view 2, and the same until the last list view i have.

but thats not a lazy load right ? i mean, when user open the activity. all data from up to bottom will load whether the user want it or not. What i want is the content load only when the user scroll down and the content is in the user view.

Here is the how i call the data chronologically

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

        listview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r)
    {
        listview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new call_data_of_listview2().execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        -- code to retrieve data from database
    }
```

Like i said before, using above code still load all data whether the user scroll the activity or not.
What i want is a lazy load or something similiar where data only load whenever the content is in the user view.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good place to implement Google's [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging), part of Jetpack. This allows you to query data only as the user requests it (usually by scrolling down the list); used in conjunction with RecyclerView and overriding RecyclerView.Adapter you should be able to get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Shoot, all the tutorial of this paging library is much more complex than what i though. Any link or reference for a newbie ?

Comment: What's confusing about it?